# Are they really using redux-saga in real projects? Is it safe to migrate from thunk to saga?

Tags: redux-saga

I am using redux-thunk in my current project. I recently found redux-saga one of our peers suggested to my teammates to migrate from thunk to saga.

**Benefits of using Saga**

1. Sagas uses generator functions the call to the fetch api with the
   yield keyword will block until the promise is resolved.
2. Unit testing is easy in saga as compared to thunk.

By simply looking those above two benefits I dont want to migrate to saga.
Is there any advantage of using saga? If so please advice me.

Comment: 2. is a flat out lie, or at the very least highly debatable. 1. is no different than thunk. You have to decide wether the complexity/convenience tradeoff is worth it for you.

Comment: @timotgl You could write your thunks in a way that would make them as easily testable as sagas, but you won't. The way sagas are written as coroutines forces you to write - besides other things - code that is easier to test, as coroutines allow you to tap into the internal code, instead of just input/output, which is important since thunks are expected to have side effects.

Comment: Regarding point 1, you can use async/await in thunk to block, but a) generators are better supported, which granted isn't really a problem when using babel b) You will need to include some Promise library for anything fancier like race, canceling etc. and you still won't be able to wait/block till another action happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is more to sagas than just that. The ability to wait for actions allows for lots of solutions that aren't possible with thunks.

On the one hand you can better decouple your side effects, like waiting for a collection to update instead of explicitly calling every thunk you need from the "update collection thunk". On the other hand you can write very complex async side effects in one short easy to understand saga, like when you need to do something once multiple actions are dispatched in order.

To answer your title questions, yes there are lots of companies using sagas in production, including the one I work in.

Comment: Thanks martin for the info.

Comment: And I bet there are more who don't use it and are doing just fine.

Comment: You could say that about any library  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of personnel choice. If team member wants to use it, look for the efforts and time taken to refactor and test.

fetch api call both does the same task where saga uses generator function.